# Individually shorten URLs in Hive

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql

I have URLs of the following structure:

```
https://pinball.globalzone.com/en_US/home?tic=1-dj33jl-dj33jl&goToRegisterNow=true
```

What I want to do now is to shorten the URLs to be able to group and count similar URL patterns. For instance, I want to cut out `https://`, the locale `en_US/` and the token `?tic=1-dj33jl-dj33jl` while keeping the rest. The result should look as follows:

```
pinball.globalzone.com/home&goToRegisterNow=true
```

I tried to achieve that by using `regexp_extract` but this method only lets me extract specific pieces that are always at the same position.

The bigger problem is that the parts I want to cut out are either individual/rule-based (i.e. the locale always contains of two lower case and two upper case letters separated by a underscore) or unique with no guaranteed length (i.e. the token).

Moreover, my resultset will also contain URLs with a different pattern in which I only want to cut the existing parts (e.g. `https://pinball.globalzone.com/en_US/forgottenPassword`, in which only `en_US/` has to be cut out).

If I would have to solve the problem quickly I would just get URLs and write some piece of Java or R code to split the get URLs into pieces and iterate through the array while cutting out all parts I don't need. However, I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to get this result straight out of Hive.

Comment: Is the token always the first parameter?

Comment: And shouldn't `https://` be removed in your second example?

Comment: Yes, `tic=` always identifies the token. And the second example represents the base URL before cutting anything. But yes, `https://` needs to be cut out as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
(?:https?:\/\/|\/[a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}|[?&]tic=[^&?]*)
```

It matches the parts you've described as unwanted. Replace that with an empty string should leave you with what you want.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wN1jA5/2).

**Edit**

Updated to check for `tic=`. Should make it more stable.

And I don't know if it's what you want, but this one allows `tic=` to be any parameter, not only the first:

```
(?:https?:\/\/|\/[a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}|[?&]tic=[^&?\n]*)
```

[Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wN1jA5/3)